# mysql w/ mysqli or PDO fail to find stored procedure when schema name includes '.' characters

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli, escaping, schema

First, I have read and googled on this issue extensively using various combinations of the the search terms php pdo or mysql database name escape. Sadly, I have not found anyone dealing with this same issue.

I have a mysql database with a schema named `www.company.com`

Generally this is not an issue, as it can easily be escaped using the back tick character.

However, when using mysqli or PDO to call a stored procedure in that schema, it always returns:
`PROCEDURE www.company.com.usp_stored_procedure_name does not exist`

Obviously, this is a simple mater of putting ` characters around the `www.company.com` however I cannot find away to do this using either mysqli or PDO. I have also failed to find reference to this issue in the documentation.

I should also point out that this procedure runs just fine from mysql command line client or from MySQL Workbench as in those cases I can include the back ticks or a `use` statement. Furthermore, I've already verified that this is not related to database user permissions.

However, every time I try to use the stored procedure through mysqli or PDO I receive the error above.

As this procedure is responsible for ETL operations and returns multiple results sets, converting it to individual statements called from php would be very painful. I am desperately hoping that someone has dealt with this problem before.

---

The following are some of the methods tried:
Note: back-tick nesting seems to cause a mess w/ the forum, so I've used the '-' character in place of a `

I've tried using an escaped database name when calling to mysqli_connect...
`$mysqli=mysqli_connect($host, $this->db->username, $this->db->password, '-www.company.com-');`
...and received an error.

I've tried calling the stored procedure w/o a database name...
`$mysqli->multi_query("CALL usp_stored_procedure_name(50, '2013-05-01')");`
...and received the error referenced above.

I've tried calling the stored procedure w/ a database name...
`$mysqli->multi_query("CALL -www.company.com-.usp_stored_procedure_name(50, '2013-05-01')");`
...and received the error referenced above.

Comment: Show some source code.

Comment: did you look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285512/fatal-error-while-calling-mysql-stored-function-from-php-using-mysqli does that help ?

Comment: How are you calling it? `$mysqli->query("CALL \`my.proc\`(@param1)");` should work just fine

Comment: Maximus2012: Not only have I already reviewed that post, I have also addressed the issue of database permissions in my original post.